# MySQL, How to add a points system? (stacking variables in a row.)

Tags: php, mysql

What I am trying to do is add a points system to my script that will add a small point value to their row, I have tried the following queries to my database. (Not all at once, lol)

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `users` SET `points` = '$points' WHERE `username` = '$username'";
$query = "UPDATE `users` SET `points` + 5 WHERE `username` = '$username'";
$query = "UPDATE `users` SET `points` = '$points' WHERE `username` = '$username'";
```

I have gotten it to ADD the points, but each time I do another action that would in return add more points to my current point balance it just updates with that amount of points, instead of adding that sum of points to the already existing balance.

edit:

The variable for points that I was using is:

```
$points + 5; OR $points = $points + 5;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Close. Try this:

```
$query = "UPDATE `users` SET points = points + 5 WHERE `username` = '$username'";
```

Comment: Top voted answer worked, cannot accept the answer for another 9 minutes. Thank you @SeanWM ! :)